# Start selenium slave on start-up using batch file

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-agent

I am trying to create a batch file that will connect slave node to master jenkins on boot.

I can successfully connect by manually typing:

```
java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://jenkinsURL:8080/jenkins/computer/Selenium%20Slave/slave-agent.jnlp -secret secret key
```

But when I try running the script that has the exact same command, it returns `Failing to obtain http://jenkinsurl:8080/jenkins/computer/Selenium0Slave/slave-agent.jnlp?encrypt=true` and fails to process the connection.

Batch script:

```
start cmd /k java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://jenkinsurl:8080/jenkins/computer/Selenium%20Slave/slave-agent.jnlp -secret secretkey
```

Why does it return different URL when executed with a batch file?
If anyone has successfully done this I would really appreciate your feedback. Thanks!

Comment: The percent symbol is a special character in a batch file.  To escape the percent symbol in a batch file you need to double the percent symbol in your code.

Comment: @Squashman Oh you are right! I got it to work after re-naming the slave and editing the script accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Manual typing: "... secret key"
but
Batch script: "... secretkey"